# How to change the date format in Bootstrap date picker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my form I have below code to display the `date picker`. I am using `bootstrap`

```
                         <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="Quantity" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Required Date</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <div class="input-group">                                        
                                        <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The date format I get is MM/DD/YYYY. But the format I need is DD/MM/YYYY. How can I change this? If I can add attribute to the form field that is better instead of javascript of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the format once in `jQuery`.

```
// here assumed that `datepicker` is the class name for using date picker
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});

// as per your code, you can update for specific id
$('#date').datepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

Comment: well thats not the class name. I can define a ID anyway. But in which element should I define it?

Comment: Yup agreed. its up to you. I added that like you can set a format for all date pickers on whole site :) kindly do accept answer.

Comment: No, the answer didnt solve the issue. To which element I should add the ID? can you update your answer with the HTML changes with relevant JQuery changes as well?

Comment: Please have a look now the answer. I added with both options. either update for an id or for whole site as format level stuff should be done site level.

Comment: Just tried, unfortunatly no good :( I get this error in console - `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function`

Comment: OK can you try now I have updated. `datepicker` instead of `datetimepicker`